# How to move focus at navigationbar's BarButtonItem in apple tv?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvos9.1, tvos10

I am working on apple tv application.I want to move focus on navigation bar's BarButtonItem.

actually when view controller hasn't any button or text field then focus moved on BarButtonItem but when I added button in view controller then focus not able to move at BarButtonItem.

can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I am able to move focus at BarButtonItem in navigation control. I think the best way to making tv app design is put view or button by vertical and horizontal axis appropriate.

You have to put button or view by horizontal and vertical axis wise. otherwise, for moving focus from one button to another, you have to add UIfocasGuide in your view.

At the time when I ask the question I had not the put button with appropriate axis wise so I was not able to move focus BarButtonItem but after done those way I am able to move focus at BarButtonItem in a navigation controller.